# Toggle function based on change of observable

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, toggle, durandal, observable

In **Durandal** I'm looking for a way to quickly initialize active toggle button by assigning `viewOptions: ko.observable("small")`. At the same time when a change in `viewOptions` occurs, I would like to toggle on the button with the corresponsing `id` and toggle off all others.

Out of the several methods that I've tried none does exactly this. What is missing in the following code?

- The framework is Durandal, which is an extension of Knockout JS
- I get no response to changes of the observed variable whatsoever

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group right" id="view-selector" data-toggle="buttons" data-bind="radio: viewOptions">
    <button type="button" id="small" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'small'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop">Small</button>
    <button type="button" id="medium" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'medium'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">Medium</button>
    <button type="button" id="large" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'large'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">Large</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'knockout', 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router'], function($, jqueryui, bootstrap, ko, app, router) {
    return {
        viewOptions: ko.observable("small"),
        bindingComplete: function() { // called immediately after databinding occurs.
            alert("start"); //called
            console.log("validate: this:", this); // Object {__moduleId__: "app/view"}
            console.log("validate: viewOptions:",this.viewOptions); // OK, non-empty
            this.viewOptions.subscribe(function(newViewOptions){
                alert("Hello there!"); //never gets called
                alert(newViewOptions); //
            });
            alert("end"); //called
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ccjnj/179/ (simplified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining bits of the solutions has lead me to the answer. I realized that the event handling model in Durandal differs slightly from Knockout and the following code was needed, before I missed `ko.bindingHandlers.radio` and `bindingComplete`:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'knockout', 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router'], function($, jqueryui, bootstrap, ko, app, router) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.radio = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
            var $buttons, $element, observable;
            observable = valueAccessor();
            if (!ko.isWriteableObservable(observable)) {
                throw "You must pass an observable or writeable computed";
            }
            $element = $(element);
            if ($element.hasClass("btn")) {
                $buttons = $element;
            }
            else {
                $buttons = $(".btn", $element);
            }
            var elementBindings = allBindings();
            $buttons.each(function() {
                var $btn, btn, radioValue;
                btn = this;
                $btn = $(btn);
                radioValue = $btn.attr("id");
                $btn.on("click", function() {
                    observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(radioValue));
                });
                return ko.computed({
                    disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: btn,
                    read: function() {
                        $btn.toggleClass("active", observable() === ko.utils.unwrapObservable(radioValue));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };        
    var vm = {
        viewOptions: ko.observable(),
        bindingComplete: function() { 
            vm.viewOptions.subscribe(function(newViewOptions){
                alert("Hello there!"); 
                alert(newViewOptions);
            });
            vm.viewOptions("large");
        }
    }
    return vm;
});
```

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out, one thing I would like to note here would be : the return can be it's own variable. so you could do var vm ={...} and then "return vm;" with that instead of "this" you can use "vm" ... just something thing to think about.

Answer (score 2):

the custom binding "radio" drives the values for each toggle button from the data attribute "data-value", so you would have to specify that value for each option like :

```
 <button type="button" id="small" class="btn btn-default" data-value="small"> ...
```

and that should take care of it demonstrated in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ccjnj/171/

Comment: Can you please include this part of the code as a response to change of `viewOptions`?    `function(newViewOptions){
        alert("Hello there!");
        alert(newViewOptions);
    }`

Comment: that code throws js exception because you are trying to access viewOptions from "this" instead of "viewModel" I have added the correction in this fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/ccjnj/173/

Comment: The problem seems to be that I don't have `viewOptions` defined. Unfortunately I define `viewOptions` in return, I will try to reflect that in the code example: `return { ko.observable("large-data"); }`

Comment: I am bit confused here ... what is the purpose of that code? if you want to be notified when "viewOptions" changes every time then one way of doing it is here http://jsfiddle.net/ccjnj/175/.

Answer (score 1):

You use [the `css` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html), telling it to apply the `active` class when `viewOptions() == 'small'` (or medium, or large):

```
<button ... data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'small'}">...</button>
```

Example:

```js
var viewModel = {
    viewOptions: ko.observable("small"),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

loop();

function loop() {
  viewModel.viewOptions("small");
  setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.viewOptions("medium");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.viewOptions("large");
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(loop, 3000);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group right" id="view-selector" data-toggle="buttons" data-bind="radio: viewOptions">
    <button type="button" id="small" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'small'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop">Small</button>
    <button type="button" id="medium" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'medium'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">Medium</button>
    <button type="button" id="large" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'large'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">Large</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

I removed the subscription from the above because I thought you were only using it for setting the class. If you want the subscription *as well*, just add it back (look in the browser console):

```js
var viewModel = {
    viewOptions: ko.observable("small"),
    attached: function() {
      this.viewOptions.subscribe(function(newViewOptions){
          console.log(newViewOptions);
      }, this); // <== No need for bind, note subscribe' 2nd arg
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.attached();

var timeout = +new Date() + 10000;
loop();

function loop() {
  viewModel.viewOptions("small");
  setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.viewOptions("medium");
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.viewOptions("large");
  }, 2000);
  if (+new Date() < timeout) {
    setTimeout(loop, 3000);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group right" id="view-selector" data-toggle="buttons" data-bind="radio: viewOptions">
    <button type="button" id="small" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'small'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop">Small</button>
    <button type="button" id="medium" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'medium'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large">Medium</button>
    <button type="button" id="large" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="css: {active: viewOptions() == 'large'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">Large</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So far I understand, but the change in `valueOptions` should also trigger an observer function. That's probably all that is missing in your example.

Comment: @PeterGerhat: You have that part, with the `subscribe`. I thought you were using the `subscribe` to set the class, so I removed it as it was unnecessary. Just add it back and do whatever additional work you need inside. Side note: No need for `.bind(this)`, `subscribe` takes a second argument which is the value to use as `this` in the callback.

Comment: the trick seems to be with making it work for Durandal (or Knockout JS). The updated JS reflects the core of my problem, `viewOptions` is not defined at the time it's being called in the `attached` lifecycle callback.

Comment: @PeterGerhat: I don't know where you're calling `attached` (as it's not in your question; **all** of your question must be in the question, not just linked), but presumably it's after the main object initializer, and thus `viewOptions` **will** exist. See my second example above.

Comment: calling `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);` is already done by Durandal (or Knockout JS), calling it again in my code results in an error. I will update the code example to give all the information.

Comment: @PeterGerhat: Knockout does not call `applyBindings` for you. If you're using something that does, then of course, you want to not do it in your own code.

Comment: That's correct `applyBindings` is added by Durandal. Reference: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks.html

Comment: @PeterGerhat: So what's outstanding? Again, by the time `attached` *can* be called, `valueOptions` exists. The above works. So...?

Comment: It works in jsfiddle, but in Durandal the function to handle `valueOptions` change event is not triggered. This doesn't work even after moving it from `attached` to `bindingComplete` part of Durandal lifecycle.

Comment: @PeterGerhat: I would suspect an unrelated error elsewhere, this just isn't complicated stuff. If `attached` is called with the correct `this`, with the object as described in your question, it **will** work. Nothing for it but to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder has a good answer for you. I just thought it seemed like a good idea to make the buttons items in your viewmodel and use a `foreach` binding to render them. Saves on repetitive HTML.

```js
function buttonData(label, value) {
  return {
    label: label,
    value: value
  };
}

var viewModel = {
  buttons: [
    buttonData('Small', 'small'),
    buttonData('Medium', 'medium'),
    buttonData('Large', 'large')
  ],
  selectedButton: ko.observable("small"),
  setOption: function(data) {
    console.debug("Set option", data.value);
    viewModel.selectedButton(data.value);

  }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.selectedButton.subscribe(function(newViewOptions) {
  alert("Hello there!");
  alert(newViewOptions);
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group right" id="view-selector" data-toggle="buttons" data-bind="foreach: buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click:$root.setOption, text:label, css: { active: value == $root.selectedButton()}"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good advice, but I will save it for later when the main problem gets solved